# How can I check if this file name is created or not in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a method that checks if this file ( todayfile.txt)  is created if not I need it to create it. Here is what I thinking of :

```
private void ReadWater()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader inputFile;

            // I want to check if there is a file named ( Todayfile.txt )

            if (// if this file ( Todayfile.txt) is founded)
            {
                // Do this
            }

            else // if there is no file in this nmae ( Todayfile.text )
            {
                // create a new file 
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Try `File.Exists(path)`.

Comment: And please don't do `catch (Exception ex)` - that's a bad practice and just hides errors. If you think an exception can be thrown and that you can **handle it meaningfully** then catch **that specific exception only**.

Comment: Copying and pasting the title into Google returns `File.Exists`.

Comment: Enigmativity is right. File.Exist(path) will return a bool == true if the file exists.  I am quite surprised you couldn't find this question elsewhere without having to post a question.  There should be plenty of documentation out there using a simple google search.  One thing you should know is you have to use the full path name.  Also, you need to escape the slashes by doing a double slash or you can just add an "@" symbol at the beginning of the string which will tell it to treat escape characters literally.

Comment: As noted by others, this answer can easily be found online with a simple search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [System.IO.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to check for and create the file.

The following example demonstrates how to use the `File` class to check whether a file exists, and depending on the result, either create a new file and write to it, or open the existing file and read from it.

```
private void ReadWater()
{
    string path = "Todayfile.txt";
    // if there is no file in this name ( Todayfile.txt )
    if(!System.IO.File.Exists(path)) {
        // Create a file to write to.
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) {
            sw.WriteLine("Hello");
            sw.WriteLine("And");
            sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
        }
    }
    //at this point file should exist.

    // Open the file to read from.
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)) {
        string s = "";
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    } 
}
```

check the links provided above to get a more detailed explanation of the `System.IO.File` class and its methods.

Comment: @Upvoters, how do you think this code works.. One condition opens for write, and the other for read. If you were the coder, how would you use that `fileStream` BTW: `File.Exists` is suggested 15 mins before that answer which doesn't add any value to that comment....

Comment: `File.Exists` was only part of the answer being sought by the OP.

Comment: Your code is still buggy, You lost the file pointer after `System.IO.File.Create(path);` You can not write to this file anymore since it is still open :)

Comment: Nkosi, this is your answer... I only say your code is not correct.... How to correct is your problem. If you don't know, don't post an answer.....

Comment: @Eser noted and understood. just trying to help. which is what I thought the site was all about.

Comment: Helping can only be done with correct answers.....

Comment: @Eser, you are correct.

Comment: And for your last edit, what if the file *exists*. Just repeat the code in `// Add some information to the file.` part?

Comment: The OP only stated he wanted to check if the file existed and if not create it. So i stopped there.

Comment: A good example for  how a simple problem can get quite complex with a bad coding....

Comment: noted also:) not to get rude as most of SO users do when someone criticizes their answer.

Comment: I wasn't being rude. If it came across so then that was not my intention.

Comment: No I didn't say that. In fact, I thank to you for it.. This  is not a common  ( polite ) response for me when I write a comment for answers..